# Why are my TIF files giving me an 'internal error' when I open them in Google Earth Pro after exporting from Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-earth-engine, satellite-image

There are plenty of tutorials out there - it's just that none of them work for me. Even when copying the code to the letter, GEE will throw a multitude of errors. Even when I get it to export a TIF file, that just bugs out when opened in Google Earth Pro.

I have tried too many scripts to recount here. All I'm looking for is some basic code to export an image collection that works. The closest I have gotten is this:

```
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')

// Load Landsat 8 imagery and filter it  
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("ASTER/AST_L1T_003") 
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2013-10-01', '2013-12-01'))
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .select(['B01', 'B02'])

// export collection to google drive
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(
  collection, 
 'Folder', 
  {name: 'ntl_{system:index}',
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  type: 'float',
  scale: 100,
  region: geometry});
```

This allows me to download a batch of TIF files into my Google Drive. The problem is that when I open these files in Google Earth Pro I get an internal error and the screen just becoming a large black rectangle.

My geometry is defined in the imports section, I chose a small rectangle of Kansas to try out my code.

What am I doing wrong?